# Opening Modified Jquery Accordion from External Link using PHP Get ID - Accordion doesn't work when URL without ID is accessed

Tags: php, jquery, accordion

New to JS and JQuery.  Have implemented many pre-made scripts but done very little on my own.

I have a modified JQuery Accordion which scrolls to the top of the open panel.  I've manged to create external links and access them through this method:

```
$(function() {

   $('#st-accordion').accordion({open: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>});

});
```

My link then looks like:

```
<a href="/company/index.php?id=0">About</a>
```

The problem lies in when I try to access /company/index.php without an ID the accordion doesn't load...I realize I can use /company/index.php?id=-1 and the accordion will load fine, but I am sure at some point someone will access the page without the ID and I'd like it to work...

Problem location - http://www.anvil-rock.com/contact/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try checking if the id parameter is null or not first? If it's null, either don't open the accordion, or just open the first pane?

Comment: I figured there was a simple answer, I just don't have the know how to get it done...Can you help? @user2051770